# Angular rxjs Subject : subscribing to a subject after emitting values

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, subject

I read an [article](https://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2017/09/11/subscribe-rxjs-event-after-emitted-angular/) in which it states that, if you subscribe to subject when the event has been already emitted  You would lose the emitted value. his demonstrated example is below.

```
let subject: Subject<string> = new Subject();
subject.next('test');
 
subject.subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```

But ,I have a similar approach implemented, In which first subject will emit the value , then subscribes the subject. Value is there. not lost. code is below.
In the code, we are saving authentication information in a subject. we use that in header component to show logout button and links. Question is why my code is working even though article says it won't?

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject} from "rxjs";
import { User } from "./user.model";

@Injectable({providedIn : "root"})
export class AuthService{

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){}
    
    user = new  Subject<User>();   //emit new user when login or logout or token expired

    login(email:string,password:string){
        return this.httpClient
       .post<SignUpResponse>('https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=AIzaSyBCK9B2RcL0D4Bn8YaFCxE9rBXejTLNYQY',
        {
            email:email,
            password:password,
            returnSecureToken:true
        })
       .pipe(tap( response => this.handleAuthentication(response.email,response.idToken,response.idToken,response.expiresIn)))
    }


    private handleAuthentication(email:string,userId:string,token:string,expiresIn:string){

         const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + +expiresIn * 1000)
         const user = new User(email,userId,token,expirationDate);
         this.user.next(user);
    }
}
```

Header.component.ts

```
import { Component,Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { AuthService } from "../auth/auth/auth.service";
import { DataStorageService } from "../shared/data-storage.service";

@Component({
    selector : 'app-header',
    templateUrl:'./header.component.html'
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy{

    collapsed = true;
    private subscription : Subscription;
    isAuthenticated : boolean = false;

    constructor(private dataStorageService:DataStorageService,
                private authService:AuthService){

    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.subscription =  this.authService.user.subscribe( user => {
        this.isAuthenticated = !!user; 
        console.log("User Object"); console.log(user); 
        console.log("IsAuthenticated value");  console.log(!!user);
    })
   }

    ngOnDestroy(){
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: A ReplaySubject will emit the last value to new subscribers

Comment: It's unclear from the code you posted what the result should be. The header is subscribing to the underlying user subject relatively early, so if login is called before that subscription has occurred, you're fine.

Comment: it is behaviorsubject will emit the last value. ReplaySubject will allow the values buffor allocates. But my question is not that. I am here using a plain Subject. In that first i emit the value. then subscribing. according the article value should be lost. but mine value is there.. not lost

Comment: @EvanTrimboli relatively early means ?  . which part of the code do you need.. i can update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason your example subscribe is running is because you load the Header component before you start the login process/method. `ngOnInit` of component is called before `login` method in service.

Your code run like this not the way you have described in the quesiton:

```
user = new  Subject<User>();
subject.next('test');

// then this runs in component ngOnInit 
this.authService.user.subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
});

// when you try to login from inside the component then it runs the login method with next.
login(email:string,password:string){.....
this.user.next(user);  // now this is triggered hence you don't loose the user response.
```

Comment: That code get executed. that the issue.

Comment: I have update the quesion with an image

Comment: "The only way in your example subscribe will run is if you load the Header component before you start the login process/method." does this line in the answer help it out?

Comment: Header component get initialized when the page get loaded.  in header component there is a link for login. after that only login method get called. can you explain

Comment: I have updated the answer do you follow now.